# Delete entry from a list in ISO C89

Tags: list, function, heap-memory, ansi-c

I have to develop a library function for a phonebook which uses lists.
This function has to delete the nth entry from the list.
It is a linked list,and the entries are structs which contain the strings name,srnm,nmbr,addr,the int number and the next pointer.
Every time I call the function,however,VS gives me lot of exceptions and triggered breakpoints,and says I've corrupted the heap.
I have no idea of  where I could have made this mistake that corrupts the heap.Please Help.

Here's what I've done so far :

```
typedef struct list {
  char name[20];
  char srnm[20];
  char nmbr[20];
  char addr[20];
  unsigned int number;/*Contact index*/
  struct list *next;
} entry;

static unsigned int count = 0;
static entry *hol = NULL;/*pointer to the head of the list*/

int delete_contact(unsigned int n) {
  int i=0,k=0;

  if(n>count) return -1;
  hol[n-1].next = hol[n-1].next->next;

  for(i=n;i<count;i++) {
    hol[i]=hol[i+1];
  }


  for(i=n;i<count;i++)
    hol[i].number = hol[i].number-1; /*Updates the contact index*/

  count--; /*Updates the global variable that gives the number of contacts */
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you actually mess up the second to last comment in your code (`+/`) or did you add that for this question only?

Comment: Only for this question,I didn't look for errors when i wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

## Suggested solution

`hol` is a pointer, so, `hol[n-1]` etc. might not refer to a `entry` struct in memory, consider when `n = 0`. Either way, this is not how you should access different entries in your list structure.

For a singly-linked list you have to consider 3 cases,

1. If `n = 0` (i.e. the first entry) is being deleted
2. If the entry to be deleted is somewhere inside the list
3. If the entry is the last entry in the list.

It is my understanding that `number` is the index of the list entry and that you've used dynamic memory allocation for the list entries. Furthermore, since you appear to be using the C89 standard (which does not allow loop variable initialization) I have adapted the code below as best as I could to C89, but I do not use that standard myself:

```
int delete_contact(unsigned int n) {
  int i = 0;
  int k = 0;

  // Check if the index refers to an element not included in the list
  if (n > count) { return -1; }

  entry* tmp = hol;

  if (n == count - 1) {
      // Iterate to the last entry
      while (tmp->next) {
          tmp = tmp->next;
      }

      free(tmp); // Free the list entry

      // Decrement the global counter keeping track of the
      // amount of list elements
      count--; 

      // No need to edit the contact indexes
      return;
  }

  entry* remaining_list = hol;

  if (n == 0) {
      // Free the head of the list

      hol = hol->next;
      remaining_list = hol;

      free(tmp); // tmp points to the head of the list already
  } else {
      // The list entry is somewhere inside the list
      int idx = 0;

      // Iterate until tmp points to the n-1:th entry
      while (idx < n - 1) {
          tmp = tmp->next;
          idx++;
      }

      entry *to_be_freed = tmp->next; // n:th entry
      tmp->next = tmp->next->next;
      remaining_list = tmp->next;

      free(to_be_freed);
  }

  // Decrement the contact index on all the remaining entries
  while (remaining_list) {
      remaining_list->number--;
      remaining_list = remaining_list->next;
  }

  // Decrement the global counter keeping track of the
  // amount of list elements
  count--; 

  return 0;
}
```

---

### Tips

You'd be better served by creating a more expressive list interface, possibly one that isn't bound to the values stored inside it. That way you could create a

```
list_size()
```

function and remove the global counter.

Here is a little something to get you started:

```
typedef struct node {
    void* value;
    struct node* next;
} node;

typedef struct list {
    node* head;
    node* tail;
    size_t len;
} list;
```

## Reference material

- [Linked list basics](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/LinkedListBasics.pdf)
- [Linked list exercises](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/105/LinkedListProblems.pdf)